# Display all results on one page?

Tags: pagination

But of an awkward one here.

Looking at this particular set of results from this website - https://fetlife.com/p/australia/western-australia

I’m wanting to know if there’s a way to show all results on one page, or at least substantially more than 20 per page (as there’s like 36000 members coming up!)

I need to search with a few different specific keywords, to put into a spreadsheet, and you specifically can’t search by characteristic (age/gender etc) on Fetlife.

So I’m hoping to display all results, or at least like 1000 per page or something like that.

Can anyone help?

Thanks
Katie

I spent a fair bit of time browsing the Inspect and source, and I think I came across the code that tells it to only display 20 per page, but obviously I can’t edit it because it’s not my page.

Help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Fetlife is designed as a community connection site; the designers don't want people coming into the site, looking up people around them.

So you cannot search by age, sex and location. There are places to place personal ads; those are people who are actively looking for others.

Yes, you can look at people in an area, however, it makes it hard to find people.